# What is developer mode?

Tags: windows-10

What is developer mode in Windows 10? What is 'sideload apps'?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2016: Windows has added text to explain 'sideload apps' and 'developer mode' allow you to install apps from outside the Windows 10 store.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [The Windows Club](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-windows-10):

> Windows 10 introduces a new way for development in Windows 10. You now no longer require a Developer License to develop, install or test your apps. You can just enable your Windows 10 device once for these tasks and you are all set to go. In this post we will see how to enable Developer Mode in Windows 10.

From [ghacks.net](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/13/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-windows-10-to-sideload-apps):

> This configuration option allows you to enable modes intended for development, for instance to test applications that you are developing on a live system to ensure that they work properly.
>
> ...
>
> The new method improves the implementation on Windows 8.x significantly and should make life a lot easier for developers, for instance by requiring no registration to get started or registering phones.
>
> Please note that you do get a prompt to enable Developer Mode automatically when you create a Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 app in Visual Studio on a windows 10 device. It more or less tells you where to enable the option but does not do that for you.

Source(s):

Comment: Just to confirm, this only applies to windows-10 ("metro" I think in w8) apps, right?

Comment: @Chipperyman yes it applies for modern apps a.k.a Metro, not for WindowsForms for example, at least that is what I suppose because I didn't required any license to develop on other .Net framework based technologies on Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 10.

Answer (score -3):

This setting is available in the Settings app. To access it, head to Settings > Update & Security > For Developers and select “Developer mode”.

Your Windows 10 PC will be put into Developer Mode. This works on all editions of Windows 10, including Windows 10 Home.

Comment: This doesn’t actually explain what developer mode is just how to enable it which the author already understood how to do.